# Shnayim Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-two?

### ?שנים ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 292.

You may need to be a native Israeli to come up with a lazy gematria for this one.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-one entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: When you have that line about the gematria, are you _actually_ hinting to something?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes; it's a pun.

Comment: Re "You may need to be a native Israeli": or a native of a particular _ir miklat_ in _ever haYarden_.

Comment: Ughh, every time I try to find references, all I find are records of [massacres](http://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Fastov/holocaust/index.html) during the Holocaust. Makes me too sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Mabul - flood until Avraham Avinu was 292 years

Avraham was born in 1948 - The Mabul was in 1656

Answer (score 3):

There are 14 possible Jewish calendar combinations. In a year where the following combination happens  - גכ"ה - there are **292** days that are not Shabbos or Yom Tov (Chutz L'Aretz) and you may do Melacha.

An explanation of what גכ"ה mean.

- The first letter is the day of the week that Rosh HaShana comes out on.
- The second letter tells you whether Cheshvon and Kisleiv have both 29 days = (ח) for Chasair. If Cheshvon has 29 days and Kisleiv has 30 days then = (כ) for K'Sidran. If both Chesvan and Kisleiv have 30 days then = (ש) for Shlaima.
- The third letter is the day of the week that Pesach comes out on.